# Can ESRI iPad app consume web mapping service?

Tags: map-service, arcgis-ios

Can the ESRI app for the iPad consume regular web mapping services, or do I need to publish services for this app as Mobile project services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the Esri app for iOS can consume regular mapping services. The caveat is that your map services must be shared on ArcGIS.com. You would then search for your map services via Esri's app. There's a .pdf on arcgis.com with more info:  [using map services with iOS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/iphone/AppGuide/Maps.pdf)

Edit:  Good discussion in [Esri's iOS forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/7701-Can-t-add-ArcGIS-Server?p=24131&viewfull=1#post24131).

Comment: Looks like Dave Bouwman figured it out pretty early - http://blog.davebouwman.com/add-your-own-map-services-to-arcgis-ios-apps

Comment: @wwnick- nice. looks like that post has all the info anyone would need to get going.